# Opening a new view controller after alert

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uialertview

enter code hereI am having trouble with going back to the previous view controller when alert is presented.

What I am trying to do is have the user enter in data, then an alert appear saying it was successful, then return to the previous view controller.

I currently have no code doing so and am seeking assistance with what I should put in.

```
- (IBAction)saveLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DATA"];
    NSMutableArray *currentDataArray;
    if (data == nil)
    {
        currentDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    else
    {
        currentDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data];
    }
    [currentDataArray addObject:self.textField.text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDataArray forKey:@"DATA"];
} 

- (IBAction)enterButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"enterButtonPressed");
    UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [enterAlert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//If u r using dismissing

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [enterAlert show];
}];
```

//if u r using navigation ,popViewController

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // handle completion here
    UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [enterAlert show];
}];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: That works thanks!

Are you able to tell me what CATransaction does?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Set Delegate self of your UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[enterAlert show];
```

Use Delegate Method of UIAlertviewController.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0){
        // Do your Stuff Here....
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
     }
}
```

Comment: Where would I state the view controller I want to change to?
That alone doesn't seem to take me back to the main screen

Answer (score 0):

Add the following UIAlertViewDelegate method to your implementation file:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
        didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        // If you are presenting this view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // If you are pushing this view controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Also remember to set your UIAlertView delegate to your view controller, change to the following code:

```
UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a bit more information where that first part of the code should go?

Comment: Do you want to go back to previous view controller once user tapped on "OK" button inside the UIAlertView? Or you want the UIAlertView show on screen and at the same time go back to previous view controller? I doubt the latter is doable.

Comment: I want to go to the previous view controller once the user has pressed 'OK'

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIAlertView *enterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Entry was recorded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
enterAlert.tag=100;
[enterAlert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (alertView.tag == 100) {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // Do something when ok pressed
  // If you are presenting this view controller
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

// If you are pushing this view controller
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        // Do something for other alertviewButton}

 else{// Do something with responses from other alertViews by giving tags
 }
```